# docker-compose service without a volume

Tags: docker, redis, containers, docker-volume

I have a redis service defined like this in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
redis:
  container_name: redis
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

As you can see, there's no volume(s) defined here. Will the redis database persist between calls to `docker run` / `docker-compose run`? I can see some data in the database when I use `docker run` with `redis-cli`, so I'm curios where it comes from.

Comment: the data will be there till you delete the container

Comment: So each `docker run` creates a container with its own database?

Comment: yes that is true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be happening here.

If you repeatedly run `docker-compose up -d`, it will make an effort to keep existing containers alive.  If you're in an ordinary development cycle and repeatedly `docker-compose stop app; docker-compose up --build -d`, this will only restart the containers that have stopped, so in this sequence the database container will never get stopped and deleted at all; you'll just have the same database container.

A second thing that happens is that the Redis Dockerfile declares [`VOLUME /data`](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6ec0ad5628df2404509f776e9c70fbecf5364c10/5.0/Dockerfile#L100).  If you don't specify anything else for that directory with a `volumes:` declaration, Docker creates an *anonymous volume* for that directory.  Docker Compose will keep track of these, and the anonymous volume will stay associated with the specific service until you explicitly [`docker-compose down -v`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) or you restart the service with [`docker-compose up --renew-anon-volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I used `redis-cli -h redis` as the command for `docker run`, so I never used the container's own volume. Unfortunately, there seem to be too many ways to do the same thing in docker  :)

Comment: If you’re doing something like `docker-compose run redis redis-cli ...`, that starts a new container, with a client only (`redis-cli` runs instead of a server), talking to the existing container.  That would definitely result in the same data being visible on repeated executions.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use `docker exec` to run the client in the same container where the server is running?

Comment: Personally I'd just run `redis-cli` from the host.  It doesn't really matter whether you're launching the client from the same container or a different one.